# React Atomic Design: Organization of Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a React app that is using the Atomic Design methodology. My components are organized like so:

```
components
  |--Atoms
  |   |--Header
  |   |    |--index.js
  |   |    |--index.test.js
  |   |    |--index.stories.js
  |   |--index.js
  |--index.js
```

In `Header/index.js`, I do a default export of the component. In `Atoms/index.js`, I export all components, like so:

```
export Header from './Header'
```

In `components/index.js` I export all layers, like so:

```
export * from './Atoms'
export * from './Moleclues'
```

If I ever need to use a component within another component, I require it from `components` like so:

```
import Header from './../..'
```

In my tests, I've aliased `'./../..'` to return a mock component so that way I can only test the component currently being tested.

So far, this pattern has been working well. However, I've realized that there's some sort of circular dependency. The reason I know this is because when I run my storybook app, certain containers are importing certain components, and the component will return undefined, so the container will throw an error.

This only occurs with one certain container, and only in my storybook app. I can't figure out why this container particularly decides to fail, and why only in my storybook app, so I surmise that it's because of the circular dependency. However, I want to know how I can keep all component imports static (i.e., have them read the same way so that I can continue aliasing them in webpack) while maintaining a clean directory structure.

Thank you!

Comment: Hello, are you sure you are correctly exporting your components from index.js ? `export * from "module"`does not pass default export, hence returning undefined. See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: I'm fairly certain I'm doing it correctly. In `Atoms/index.js` I am exporting all named exports, so `export * from 'module'` shouldn't run into the default export issue you mentioned.

Comment: Hello, I'm still not so sure, from the doc I referenced earlier you can read that for re-exporting default module you need to do it in to lines : 1st importing the default member, then reexporting it as a named export.

Comment: In `Atoms/index.js` I tried `import Header from './Header'` and `export default { Header }` and that still didn't work. The doc you mentioned says that `export * from 'module'` won't work if `module` is a default export, but in my case, it's not -- it's a named export. It's a named export _of_ a default export, but that should work. Plus, it's only for one single component, in one environment, so it doesn't seem like there's any syntax issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is still a mistake in the way you export members from your module

```
/*
 * Header.js
 * this exports an object { Header: Header } as default export
 *
 */
export default { Header } 


/*
 * this imports the default member of the exports
 * from the Header module in the same directory.
 * 
 */
import Header from "/Header"


/*
 * If you are transpiling with babel ( for instance ) you will have an undefined 
 * export because what you actually have is 
 */

// Header.js
exports = { Header: Header, __es6: true }

// index.js
const Header = require("./Header").default;


/*
 * Note : your first example is a syntax error and should be
 */
export { Header } from "./Header";


/*
 * to make it work correctly you need to 
 */
//Header.js
export { Header };

// index.js
export * from "./Header";

// your components
import { Header } from "path/to/dir";
// this last line will find your directory according to your webpack config, as
// it's a directory it will find the index.js and proceed from there
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not convinced that `export Header from './Header'` is incorrect, because it works perfectly fine in all my other apps and even in this app. If it were `import Header from './Header'` then it would be `export { Header }` but since I'm just re-exporting, it works fine. I also tried `export { default as Header } from './Header'` and that did not work either. As I mentioned, the production app works fine, it's just the storybook app that has this issue.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working was this:

```
import Header from './../../atoms'
```

anywhere I needed Header, as long as it wasn't within another atom.

In atomic design, you can't have a same or higher level component in a component (that is, a Molecule can't contain another Molecule or an Organism, only Atoms). Bearing that in mind, there would be no circular dependencies if we pull straight from the `atoms` folder.

`export Header from './Header'` worked fine, as did `export * from './atoms` since I resolved all default exports with the named export.

To fix the mocking issue, I just learned a bit of regex:

```
/^(./?)../../(atoms|molecules|organisms|templates|pages)$/
```

By using this regex, any time a component imported another component, it would mock every other component.